# What is this theorem called?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to search for more information about the following theorem:

> Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function in the open ball $B_R(z_0)$, such that for every $r$, $0<r<R$:
>
> $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi r}\int_{\partial B_r(z_0)}f(z)dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(z_0+re^{i\theta})d\theta$$

Comment: Isn't this Gauss' mean value theorem?

Comment: I think you have wriiten that incorrectly. First equality must be CAuchy's integral formulae! So, there is a $ (z-z_{o})$, in the denominator of  the first integrand!

Comment: ... sometimes called mean value formula

Comment: If the ball is $B_R(z_0)$, then what does the notation $\partial B_r(z_0)$ signify?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z_{0})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{r}} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz$$. This is the Cauchy's integral formula. Now we have $C_{r}(\theta) =z_{0}+re^{i\theta}$. Now use the original definition of Complex integration on a comtour to get the result which is  sometimes called the Gauss' Mean value theorem.